# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' java config based hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, config

I am getting this error:

[image]

[image]

I don´t know how can I solve this.This is my app folder:

[image]

And these are my java based config file:

[image]

Comment: show full stacktrace as text not image

Comment: Don't post code, stack traces etc. as images, post them as properly encoded text.

Answer (score 0):

you this dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

for configuration refer bellow link :

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-2-java-based-configuration

https://dzone.com/articles/springhibernate-application